# preg replace error

Tags: php

I have searched other questions, but since I'm not a PHP coder I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong when trying to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
$urlno = preg_replace("http://","",$m[m_siteurl]);
```

and

```
if (!preg_match($admfile, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) { die ("Access Denied"); }
```

I cannot figure out where to put or what to put as the delimiter.

Comment: Read the manual first

Comment: use str_replace here and you are done ... anything else - as nambi wrote ...

Comment: what is the need for the regex here?? would't [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) be enough ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delimeters for your regex and optional modifiers. This could be any char - i.e. `~`, or `/`

```
$urlno = preg_replace("~http://~", "", $m['m_siteurl']);
```

btw - you don't really need regular expressions here.. simply use str_replace

```
$urlno = str_replace("http://", "", $m['m_siteurl']);
```

instead of preg_match, you could also use strpos

```
if (!strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $admfile) !== false) { die ("Access Denied"); }
```

or if you want preg_match..

```
if (!preg_match('~' . preg_quote($admfile, '~') . '~', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) { die ("Access Denied"); }
```

Comment: last one is this one that can't seem to work either, could you fix this one please? if (!preg_match($admfile, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) { die ("Access Denied");

Answer (score 0):

You can just use str_replace instead of preg_replace, it is less memory-intensive.

```
$urlno = str_replace('http://','',$m['m_siteurl']);
```